# C# serial port close hang while close the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-port

this is my code

```
public void ClosePort()
    {
        if (comPort.IsOpen == true)
        {
            //e.Cancel = true; //cancel the fom closing
            Thread CloseDown = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CloseSerialOnExit)); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
            //comPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            //comPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            //comPort.Dispose();                
            CloseDown.Start(); //close port in new thread to avoid hang
            DisplayData(MessageType.Error, "Port communication has been closed" + " " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
        }
    }

    private void CloseSerialOnExit()
    {
        try
        {
            comPort.Dispose();
            comPort.DiscardInBuffer();
            comPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            comPort.Close(); //close the serial port
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); //catch any serial port closing error messages
        }
        BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(NowClose)); //now close back in the main thread
    }

    private void NowClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comPort.Dispose();
        comPort.DiscardInBuffer();
        comPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
        comPort.Close(); //now close the form
    }
    public void BeginInvoke(Delegate method)
    {

    }
```

why the serial port not close? and when i hit [X] Icon and exit the program, program stil detect in task manager.
In normal case, the above code is work. But when the serial do write or read data the code is not work, not close the serial port, any suggestion for this case? thanks for help and solution.

```
private void cmdClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to disconnect?", "WARNING",
        MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel);
        switch (result)
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                {
                    comm.ClosePort();

                    cmdRefresh.Enabled = true;
                    cmdNewReport.Enabled = true;
                    cboPort.Enabled = true;
                    cboBaud.Enabled = true;
                    cboStop.Enabled = true;
                    cboParity.Enabled = true;
                    cboData.Enabled = true;
                    label9.Text = " ";
                    label11.Text = " ";

                    cmdOpen.Enabled = true;
                    //cmdSend.Enabled = true;
                    cmdClose.Enabled = false;

                    break;
                }
            case DialogResult.Cancel:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

the above code is my button code which calling the comPort.ClosePort();

```
void comPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
            //determine the mode the user selected (binary/string)
            switch (CurrentTransmissionType)
            {
                //user chose string
                case TransmissionType.Text:
                    //read data waiting in the buffer
                    string msg = comPort.ReadExisting();
                    //display the data to the user
                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, msg + "\n");
                    break;
                //user chose binary
                case TransmissionType.Hex:
                    //retrieve number of bytes in the buffer
                    int OpeCode = 0;
                    int RequestID = 0;
                    int Product = 0;
                    int IPenNo = 0;
                    string status = " ";

                    while (true)
                    {
                        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;             // Use current time.
                        string format = "dddddddd, MMMMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                        string currentTime = time.ToString(format);
                        byte[] TrueData = new byte[256];

                        try
                        {
                            int bytes = comPort.BytesToRead;
                            if (bytes == 0) continue;
                            //create a byte array to hold the awaiting data
                            byte[] comBuffer = new byte[bytes];
                            comPort.Read(comBuffer, 0, bytes);
                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Hexa :" + ByteToHex(comBuffer) + "\n");
                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Byte :" + bytes.ToString() + "\n");

                            if (bytes == 3)
                            {
                                var lines = File.ReadAllLines(Fullpath).ToList();

                                // Remove as many lines as you'd like from the end
                                if (lines.Count > 2)
                                {
                                    lines.RemoveRange(lines.Count - 2, 2);
                                }

                                // Iterate backwards through the list until we've updated 2 (or more or less) lines
                                var linesUpdated = 0;

                                for (var i = lines.Count - 1; i >= 0 && linesUpdated < 1; i--)
                                {
                                    if (lines[i].Contains("OK"))
                                    {
                                        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace("OK", "NG");
                                        linesUpdated++;
                                    }
                                }

                                File.WriteAllLines(Fullpath, lines.ToArray());
                                //DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "NG" + "\n");
                            }

                            if (bytes == 2)
                            {
                                continue;
                            }

                            int etx_ok = 0;

                            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i++)
                            {
                                if (comBuffer[i] == 0x02)
                                {
                                    //DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "cek II:" + checkStatus + "\n");
                                    int length = comBuffer[i + 1];
                                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "Length=" + length.ToString() + "\n");

                                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(bytes.ToString()))
                                    {
                                        status = "NG";
                                    }
                                    if (length + i + 1 != bytes && status == " ")
                                    {
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, length.ToString() + " " + i.ToString() + " " + bytes.ToString() + " ");
                                        status = "NG";
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ERROR \n");
                                        //break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        status = "OK";
                                    }

                                    DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ini statusnya  : " + status + "\n");

                                    if (comBuffer[length + i - 1] == 0x03)
                                    {
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ETX OK\n");
                                        etx_ok = 1;
                                        OpeCode = comBuffer[i + 2];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "OpeCode=" + OpeCode.ToString() + ",");
                                        RequestID = comBuffer[i + 3];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "RequestID=" + RequestID.ToString() + ",");
                                        int StoreCode = comBuffer[i + 4];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "StoreCode=" + StoreCode.ToString() + ",");
                                        int ProductBatteryTraining = comBuffer[i + 5];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ProductBatteryTraining=" + ProductBatteryTraining.ToString() + ",");

                                        Product = ProductBatteryTraining >> 4;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Product=" + Product.ToString() + ",");
                                        int Battery = ProductBatteryTraining & 4;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Batery=" + Battery.ToString() + ",");
                                        int Training = ProductBatteryTraining & 1;
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "  Training=" + Training.ToString() + ",");

                                        IPenNo = comBuffer[i + 6];
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "IPenNo=" + IPenNo.ToString() + ",");

                                        int CrcCalc = comBuffer[length + i] + 0x11;

                                        for (int j = 7, k = 0; j < length; j++, k++)
                                        {
                                            //syswrite STDOUT , "TrueDataX " . $length . "\n";
                                            DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "TrueDataX " + length.ToString() + "," + "\n");
                                            TrueData[k] = comBuffer[i + j];
                                        }
                                        if (OpeCode == 0x63)
                                        {
                                            byte[] replyStr = new byte[] { 
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x45), Convert.ToByte(0x53), Convert.ToByte(0x4c), Convert.ToByte(0x14), Convert.ToByte(0x09), Convert.ToByte(0x00),                             //#Length Change
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x02), Convert.ToByte(0x08),Convert.ToByte(OpeCode), Convert.ToByte(RequestID),Convert.ToByte(Product-1), Convert.ToByte(IPenNo),                                       //#Reply Header Data                   
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x00),                                                                                                                                           //#Reply Status      
                                        Convert.ToByte(0x03), Convert.ToByte(CrcCalc),                                                                                                                     //#Footer Data    
                                        Convert.ToByte(0xcc), Convert.ToByte(0xcc) 
                                        };

                                            comPort.Write(replyStr, 0, replyStr.Length);

                                            //write file to textfile
                                            //string path = @"d:\yosafat\testfile\tes1_Friday0916201614.33.txt"; 
                                            string IPenID = IPenNo.ToString();
                                            string appendText = ("IPen ID \t" + "Datetime\t\t\t\t\t" + "Status" + Environment.NewLine + IPenID + "\t\t" + currentTime + "\t\t" + status + Environment.NewLine);
                                            File.AppendAllText(Fullpath, appendText);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        OpeCode = 0;
                                        //syswrite STDOUT , "ETX Bad Data" . $length . "\n";
                                        DisplayData(MessageType.Incoming, "ETX Bad Data" + length.ToString() + "\n");
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (etx_ok == 1)
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception) { }
                    }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where are these methods being called from? That's the relevant part. Also what's the idea with closing the port twice? Also, your `BeginInvoke` method is 1) empty, and 2) hides the base `Control.BeginInvoke` which you probably intended to call.

Comment: Is there a special reason to use an extra thread to close the port? And why do you call `Dispose` first and then `Close` ?

Comment: @Groo : what must i do with begininvoke ?

Comment: The SerialPort.Dispose() and Close() method (same thing) are prone to deadlock.  The kind of deadlock that is easy to debug with the debugger's Debug > Windows > Threads debugger window.  You are likely to discover that the bug is located in your DisplayData() method, using Invoke() is quite dangerous.  A method you almost never actually need, always favor BeginInvoke() instead.

Comment: so what must i do ? my work step is 1.connect to port, 2. scan and received data, 3. disconnect port and repeat previous step. is it another way based on your experience sir?